# Does AppDynamics log request and response

Tags: microservices, zipkin, appdynamics, apm, opentracing

Can AppDynamics show the request or response being exchanged between different microservices systems. They show the call trace, but couldnt find the details of what is passing between the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does transaction tracking for every intra-component call across languages. Without code changes. When there is a slow transaction detail down to code level will show up in snapshots, this is what you'd use for diagnostics. Depending on your language you can also configure data collectors which do runtime instrumentation of custom data from the code. These show up on every call, and you can turn them into metrics too. Once again no code changes.